# Popup positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am implementing a screen, but i am facing a issue that my pop up screen display in center. But i need that pop up screen just above the bottom button.

Can you please tell me how to give position of my pop up screen as same as in this pic.
Here is my code.

here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/q2pWL/20/

```
<div data-role="page" id="foo">
    <div data-role="header"style="background: green;">
        <h1>Wbservice</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content"></div>

    <!--pop up screen-->
    <div data-role="popup" id="webservice" data-close-btn="none" >
        <div data-role="header"style="background: green;">
            <h1>Wbservice new/edit</h1>
        </div>

        <input name="webserviceName" value="" type="text" autocapitalize="off" placeholder="Name the web Service">
        <input name="Address" value="" type="text" autocapitalize="off" placeholder="Address of webservice">
    </div>
    <!-- /content -->

    <div class="customFooter" data-role="footer">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/42x42" id="Test"/>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/42x42"/>
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>

    </div>
    <!-- /header -->
</div>
<!-- /page -->
```

Comment: Check the below answer

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/q2pWL/23/ check this. And check my answer on your previous answer.

Comment: Thanks omar ..But there is no black background and arrow key in this pop up can we add that arrow key in our pop up

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/bNJt5/

Comment: Thanks one more question ?

Comment: how to add scroll able  list view as show in image with small width in contend page

Comment: You're welcome. its better to post it in a separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a triangle to your popup div, and position popup using (x,y) coordinates.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/bNJt5/)**

**CSS**

```
.tooltip_arrow {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -9px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px 10px 0 10px;
  border-color: #000 transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="popup" id="webservice" data-close-btn="none">
  <div data-role="header" style="background: green;">
    <h1>Wbservice new/edit</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <input name="webserviceName" value="" type="text" autocapitalize="off" placeholder="Name the web Service" />
    <input name="Address" value="" type="text" autocapitalize="off" placeholder="Address of webservice" />
    <div class="tooltip_arrow"></div> <!-- arrow div -->
  </div>
</div>
```

**Position popup and change background-color**

```
$("#Test").on('click', function () {
  var x_pos = $(this).offset().left,
      y_pos = $(this).offset().top;
  $('#webservice').popup("open", {
    x: x_pos,
    y: y_pos
  });
  $('#webservice').css('background', 'black'); /* change color here */
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19315321/how-to-add-scrollable-list-having-width-less-than-window-width-and-a-fixed-heigh

Answer (score 1):

Try this one to `positionTo` Test div

```
$("#Test").click(function(){
     $('#webservice').popup("open",{positionTo: '#Test'})

});
```

This option can be also exposed as a `data attribute: data-position-to="#Test"` in your popup div

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5RGH/)**

**[jQuery Mobile Popup Options Doc](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/options.html)**

Comment: How to add background image of page (grayish one) in contend ?